# What is the best way to synchronize files to a VFAT partition?

Tags: file-copy, synchronization, vfat

POSIX filenames may contain all characters except `/`, but some filesystems reserve characters like `?<>\\:*|"`. Using `pax`, I can copy files while replacing these reserved characters:

```
$ pax -rw -s '/[?<>\\:*|\"]/_/gp' /source /target
```

But `pax` lacks an `--delete` option like `rsync` and `rsync` cannot substitute characters. I'm looking for a simple way to backup my music collection to an external hard drive on a regular basis.

Comment: Have you looked at this method using rsync? http://serverfault.com/questions/54949/how-can-i-use-rsync-with-a-fat-file-system

Comment: Thanks, good to know about the `--modify-window` option for `rsync`. But it does not solve the character substitution.

Comment: I could not find any other method to do what you're asking. Not saying it doesn't exist, but while researching this I found nothing promising.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this, but I will comment that I think your list of reserved characters is incomplete. AFAIK `+` and possibly `;` should be in there. Only way to be sure is to test though...

Comment: What does rsync do when it meets these characters, anyway. Do you get an IO error?

Comment: `rsync` says: Invalid argument. `strace` gave me: `open(".foo\\bar.VVfqTX", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)`. I guess this is because of the underlying filesystem telling the kernel not to accept the backslash character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a view of the FAT filesystem with POSIX semantics, including supporting file names with any character other than `/` or a null byte. [POSIXovl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/posixovl/) is a relatively recent [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem for this.

```
mkdir backup-fat
mount.posixovl -S /media/sdb1 backup-fat
rsync -au /source backup-fat/target
```

Characters in file names that VFAT doesn't accept are encoded as `%(XX)` where `XX` are hexadecimal digits. As of POSIXovl 1.2.20120215, beware that a file name like `%(3A)` is encoded as itself, and will be decoded as `:`, so there is a risk of collision if you have file names containing substrings of the form `%(XX)`.

Beware that POSIXovl does not cope with file names that are too long. If the encoded name doesn't fit in 255 characters, the file can't be stored.

POSIXovl stores unix permissions and ownership in files called `.pxovl.FILENAME`.

Comment: Available as Debian package (`fuse-posixovl`) and works like a charm.

Comment: Available as posixovl under openSUSE.

Answer (score 2):

I was curious about this so I did a bit of digging.

There are a couple of patches to do this that never made it into rsync, if you fancy compiling from source. Although both are old so they may not still work. This one specifically adds a [`--fat-filenames` option](http://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2009-January/022560.html) and this one for a [`--tr` option](https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync-patches.git;a=blob;f=transliterate.diff;h=77f9ed8add21b705017c1809e99391cc5414de00;hb=5214a41bbae94607b196b199b483710e1babf292).

These questions also cover something similar - [Rsyncing files with special characters to USB FAT32](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70785/rsyncing-files-with-special-characters-to-usb-fat32) and https://askubuntu.com/questions/11634/how-can-i-substitute-colons-when-i-rsync-on-a-usb-key. The best bet is probably rdiff-backup which does the substitution, but I can't see any options to have any control over it. There are some other good ideas too though.

A rough idea for a script that would delete and recreate the files each time, if there are not too many, would be something like:

```
[sudo] updatedb      # doing this as root will update the system database
locate -r '^/full/path/to/source/.*[?<>\\:*|\"]' |
  sed 's\^/full/path/to/source/\\' >bad_names
rsync --delete --exclude-from=bad_names -av source/ target
cd source
<bad_names pax -rw -s '/[?<>\\:*|\"]/_/gp' target
```

`locate` would be faster than `find` if the database is reasonably up to date.

Finally you could just do this so that the files don't cause any more problems (at least the currently existing ones):

```
find source/ -regex '[?<>\\:*|\"]' -exec rename 's/'[?<>\\:*|\"]'/_/g' {} +
```

I would recommend trying that with `rename -n` first though in case something goes wrong.

Comment: thanks for investigating. A pity rsync didn't include those pataches. If a skript will be the solution, your ideas will come in very handy.