# How can I copy files with characters like '?' and ':' from a read-only drive to ntfs?

Tags: ntfs, hfs+

I have a drive of files recovered from a mac (hfs+) that I'm trying to copy over to an ntfs volume so that they can be accessed from a Windows machine. There are, unfortunately, quite a few files with characters that won't copy.

This is a very similar question to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150637/copy-filenames-with-special-characters-to-an-external-ntfs-volume), but I've tried both mounting the ntfs volume with the windows_names option, and using rsync with the iconv option (with utf-8 and utf-8-mac in different orders, or with '.'), both without success. To my understanding, I also can't use the detox option, as I can't write to the drive with the original files (journaled hfs+ can only be mounted read-only on linux).

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04, and I've tried copying from the GUI and rsync so far.

If it helps, with the ntfs drive mounted with the 'windows_names' option, I use

```
sudo rsync --append-verify -r <source> <dest>
```

and get

```
rsync: open "/location/Reunion??.rtf" failed: Invalid argument (22)
```

from files with invalid characters.

Can I maybe pipe the files through detox somehow so that they're not writing to the original drive or the destination that won't accept the invalid characters? Do I have to change all the files manually? Is there a regex script option, maybe?

Comment: I had a problem like this once. Never figured out how to do it right. I ended up renaming the files in the source file system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rsyncing files with special characters to USB FAT32](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70785/rsyncing-files-with-special-characters-to-usb-fat32)

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but I solved this by using an ext4 drive as an intermediate location. I copied the files from the hfs+ drive to an ext4, then used detox, then copied the files again over to the ntfs drive.

Answer (score 1):

A related question solved this with a custom bash script, which basically iterates through the files and renames them on-the-fly to the destination drive, changing colon `:` and question-marks `?` to underscores `_`: [Rsyncing files with special characters to USB FAT32](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70785/rsyncing-files-with-special-characters-to-usb-fat32)

You simply need to rename the source/destination directories in the shell script.