# Back In Time - Program: failed: Invalid argument (22)

Tags: linux-mint, backup, backintime

I'm trying to backup my computer files on an external hard drive using the "Back In Time" program for linux, but after the backup finishes, it says that the backup has errors. When I click on the View Last Log button, to see the errors, it shows me a large list of files that were not backed up.

**Error looks like this:**

```
[E] Error: rsync: mkstemp <filename and location> failed: Invalid argument (22)
```

When I look for the file that had the error, its not there in the backup on the external hard drive. So Back in Time is not backing up the files that give the errors. It does backup all of the other files, but not the ones with the errors.

If anyone can hep me figure out the problem, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

**OS:** Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon

**Back In Time Version:** 1.3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rsyncing files with special characters to USB FAT32](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70785/rsyncing-files-with-special-characters-to-usb-fat32)

Comment: Thank you, but I figured out the problem. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. When I formatted my backup hard drive, I didn't set the type to Ext4. In my disk manager, I can see that my computer's hard drive is using Ext4. So I formatted my backup hard drive, set the type to Ext4, and now everything is working correctly.